# Big Intersection equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Having some trouble solving these:

$$\large \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n,\infty)=\emptyset$$

and

$$\large \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{k}(n,\infty)\neq \emptyset$$
for $k>1$.

*I tried induction here, but I got stuck in the $n+1$ stage.

Stuck on it for hours. any help will he appreciated

Comment: Do you understand *why* the statements are true?

Comment: Induction is probably not a good strategy here. Just prove it directly instead.

Comment: Suppose that the infinite intersection contains a point $a$.  Then you can find an integer $m$ such that $m>a$, meaning that $\lbrace a\rbrace \not\subset (m,\infty)$, and so the intersection is empty.  I'll let you think about the finite case yourself.

Comment: Yes it is pretty clear that they are true.

Comment: You only need to apply the definition of set, what elements belongs to these sets? Observe that normal induction is not useful here because induction only can prove statements for natural numbers, but infinity is not a natural number.